# Using Mongoose save() inside Formidable's parse() inside NextJS API

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose, next.js, request-promise

Am using `formidable` package and `mongoose` in my NextJS app. So I wrote the API call to allow user to upload a photo along with some data. And I process the files using the `formidable` and it's working fine. But after processing the file, I need to insert some data to my MongoDB through `mongoose` and then return the API response. If I use `await` on the `save()` method of mongoose to save the data, it throws the error saying the parent needs to be async function. But in my case, the parent is `form.parse()`.

Am a bit confused here on how to solve this issue. I think am confused with Promises here.

Here's the stripped down code of my `/pages/api/submit.js` :

```
import dbConnect from '../../lib/dbConnect'
import User from '../../models/User'
import formidable from 'formidable'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    await dbConnect()

    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        // some config
        form.uploadDir = './public/photos/';

        form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
            //.. some logic

            if (err) {
                console.log('error parsing the file')

                return res.status(400).json( {
                    error: true,
                    msg: "Unable to parse the file"
                } )
            }

            // insert some data
            var user = new User( { name: 'blah', file_name: 'x', file_size: 'xx' } );
            //await user.save();
            user.save( err => {
                if( err ){
                    console.log( err )
                    return false
                }

                // success
                res.status(200).json( {
                    error: false,
                    msg: "success"
                } ).end()
            } )
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unwrap it from the callback-hell, so you have a nice async/await code

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-nextform-htl6j?file=/pages/api/update.js)

```
const asyncParse = (req) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      // resolve "returns" the promise so you will have a straighforward logic flow
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log("Receiving");
  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    const result = await asyncParse(req);
    // so you can use it here as a normal code flow
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  }
}
```

PS. Why necrobumping? Its one of the first Google results, sorry